# Setting specific image brightness

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'll get this out of the way at the start: this might be a really stupid question, and it may also belong on a different SE, so please feel free to tell me if that's the case.

I have a bunch of images, which are merges of a greyscale and green channel. Some of the images are much darker than others, while the rest are all approximately the same.

I'd like to 'homogenise' the brightness of the set of images as best as I can (it doesn't have to be perfect).

Does anyone know if there is a reasonably simple way to do this?

This is how I'm thinking to do it at present, utilising ImageMagick (a bit of `bash`  pseudo- and actual code, since I'm using CLI imagemagick on OSX, but other solutions would be fine):

#### Step 1

Read in my set of 'reference images' with a brightness/grey level I'm OK with and get an average grey level:

```
greyvals = ()
for file in an_array_of_image_files ; do
     # get array of grey values
     greyval=$(convert $file -colorspace Gray -format "%[mean]" info:)
     greyvals+=$greyval

# average the greyvals of the reference set through some mean function.
```

#### Step 2

This is where my question really lies. Is there a way to brighten or darken an image to a specified grey level?

ImageMagick provides the `modulate` function, but the examples I've found so far require a percentage 'brightening/darkening', e.g.:

```
convert $file -modulate 200% ${file%.*}_bright.png
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely?

---

EDIT

Some example images:

A reference 'bright enough' image:

[image]

An example 'dark' image:

[image]

Histogram equalisation image - this appears to work quite nicely, but is introducing some white artifacts in certain regions.
[image]

Comment: I think your question fits here.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in ImageMagick, so won't post an answer. But look for histogram equalization. It's the standard way of making multiple images have a uniform brightness. It makes it so that the image has an approximately uniform intensity distribution (the histogram will be more or less flat), but can also be used to force one image's intensity distribution to match another image's.

Comment: You can do image matching in various ways: histogram matching, brightness/contrast (mean/std) matching or gaussian redistribution or histogram equalization. ImageMagick bash shell scripts for, histmatch, match image and redist can be found on my site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. ImageMagick has a function, -level, which is like Photoshop/GIMP levels. Brightness/contrast adjustments usually are relative (changes often as percent), not absolute gray level. In ImageMagick you can change any range of gray levels to one particular value using -fuzz ... -fill ... -opaque

Comment: @fmw42 those scripts are really helpful thank you! I've added some example images though as its causing some white artifacts in the images (which I can avoid by just directly scaling the brightness by some %), so I'm wondering if you have any suggestions for a slightly different approach that might not give these artifacts?

Comment: I'm not at a machine to test, but you could try converting to HSL colourspace and doing an `-auto-gamma` on the Lightness channel, something like `magick input.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel B -auto-gamma -colorspace sRGB output.jpg`

Comment: `@Joe Healey`. The match image script may work better. Have you tried that? Also as Mark Setchell has mentioned using another colorspace or channel. That can be selected in the histmatch and matchimage scripts. Histogram equalization can produce harsh looking results. I prefer the contrast/brightness (mean/std) approach as per my matchimage script. For a simple command, try GeeMack's command below. I note that your dark image does not show the green areas. Is that expected? How important are the green areas? Do they change from image to image?

Comment: I did try it briefly, though didn't mess with it as much as the histmatch. It looks like the HSL colorspace will offer the best results (I only tested rgb, luminance, gray).

The green areas are important, but as long as their brightness scales with the rest of the image - that's fine for what I need. I have a range of images where some have brighter green patches and others are `duller'. Perhaps I picked a bad couple of examples - but the short answer is yes, the green is important (it just so happened that that 'dark' image also has less green in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my ImageMagick scripts, histmatch and matchimage, here are a few results using your two images. ImageMagick 6.9.9.43 Q16 and Mac OSX Sierra.

```
histmatch -c rgb reference.jpg dark.png dark_histmatch_rgb.png
```

[image]

```
histmatch -c gray reference.jpg dark.png dark_histmatch_gray.png
```

[image]

```
matchimage -c hsi dark.png reference.jpg dark_matchimage_hsi.png
```

[image]

```
matchimage -c ycbcr dark.png reference.jpg dark_matchimage_ycbcr.png
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising with the `hsi` colourspace on the `matchimage` script, thanks! I'll play with it on a few more images and report back

Comment: `matchimage -c hsi` has had the desired effect without any artifacting, so thanks a ton! I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: out of interest, will you ever be putting the scripts on github? Or do you have quick/easy way of downloading them all? I can see many of them being useful to me in future.

Comment: Sorry, no current plans to put them on GitHub at the moment and I do not have a mass download feature as I want to track how many of each are of real interest.

Answer (score 2):

Using ImageMagick 7 I would consider this approach...

```
magick input.png -brightness-contrast %[fx:50-(mean*100)] output.png
```

That would adjust every input image to have a 50% mean brightness overall. Using IM6 you can get the required value into a variable with a command like this...

```
adjuster=`convert input.png -format %[fx:50-(mean*100)] info:`
```

Then use that variable as an argument for the "-brightness-contrast" operator in a command like my IM7 example above, something like this...

```
convert input.png -brightness-contrast $adjuster output.png
```

I haven't tested this from a *nix command line, but the concept should work.