# How to adjust -brightness-contrast of multiple JPG files using imagemagick?

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have ~500 JPG pictures like this:

[image]

it has a watermark on it.

I want to set these pictures to `brightness=10` so that the watermark will vanish

[image]

I use imagemagick 7.1.1-18 on Archlinux

I tried `magick ./*.jpg -brightness-contrast %[fx:50-(mean*100)] output.png` on [Setting specific image brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335759/setting-specific-image-brightness) but it said
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

---

PS: the watermark is “好学近乎知 PDG” (To be fond of learning is to be near to knowledge PDG) which can be found at PDF files converted from PDG encrypted files in [www.chaoxing.com](http://www.chaoxing.com) (超星) which is a major Chinese E-book library. To remove the watermark we can set the brightness to 110 (cite from https://blog.csdn.net/shine78/article/details/8039265)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite simple

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*.jpg; do
    magick "$filename" -brightness-contrast 10 "$filename"
done
```

Comment: If that command does what you want, you'd be better off using `mogrify` as follows `magick mogrify -brightness-contrast 10 *.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this in Imagemagick is to use white-thresholding. It makes all values above the threshold to white, but keeps the values below the threshold unchanged.

Input:

[image]

convert -quiet img.jpg -white-threshold 90% result.png

[image]